# when to use NPN_ReleaseVariantValue in plugin?

Tags: npapi

When to use ReleaseVariantValue() is not clear to me, I already read
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NPN_ReleaseVariantValue
http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/the-opera-plug-in-interface/#NPN_ReleaseVariantValue

Can you please tell me in which usecase shall we use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can uses this to flush the value held for any variant - string, object etc. The browser internally clears the value based on the object type. This may also mean deallocating memory

As per MDC,

*"This must always be called on result variants and such in this API, i.e. any NPVariant whose value comes from a call that passes back an NPVariant must be released using this function. "*

So, if you use some calls that put the result in an (NPVariant *) like NPN_Invoke() or NPN_GetProperty(), you should use NPN_ReleaseVariantValue() to clear them

See also:
http://colonelpanic.net/2009/12/memory-management-in-npapi/